# Number of comments left on other people's posts in the past 90 days from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I have this fql query but its making me wrong result

SELECT created_time,message,description FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND comments.count>0 and created_time > 1343904949 limit 100000

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to go so far back in time(90 days). From my experience i received an maximum of 6 days in the past.

This fql query will return the news feed posts with the accompanying comments:

```
SELECT created_time, message, description, comments FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed')AND is_hidden = 0 AND comments.count > 0 LIMIT 5000
```